# How to render controller without container tag in table?

Tags: ember.js

I have really enormous table to handle in Ember.js. At this moment I am using to this job single controller, but it breaks single responsibility principle.

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>First column in first group</th>
     <th>Second column in first group</th>

     <th>First column in second group</th>
     <th>Second column in second group</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td>{{controller.someAction}}</td>
     <td>{{controller.otherAction}}</td>

     <td>{{controller.someAction2}}</td>
     <td>{{controller.otherAction2}}</td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Instead I would like to group couples of related actions in one controller.

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>First column in first group</th>
     <th>Second column in first group</th>

     <th>First column in second group</th>
     <th>Second column in second group</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     {{render 'firstGroup' this}}
     {{render 'secondGroup' this}}
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

However, it is not going to work. Ember will place firstGroup in some kind of tag (for instance `div`), which can't be located directly beetwen `<tr>` and `<td>`. I can't use neither `<tr>`, nor `<td>` for rendering container.

It would be great if ember could render controller without container's tag. Is there any way to deal with that? Maybe there is special tag in HTML which won't breake my table layout and can be placed in that position? "Actions" in my controller are only calculating values based on model. Maybe Should I use something other than controller?

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no.

You can define the tag to be used for a particular view, unfortunately having it host multiple columns using render would be difficult.  So you'd likely need to break it down to individual TDs using render.

```
<tr>
  {{render 'firstGroup' this}}
  {{render 'secondGroup' this}}
  {{render 'thirdGroup' this}}
  {{render 'fourthGroup' this}}
</tr>

App.FirstGroupView = Em.View.extend({
  tagName:'td'
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jafanitu/1/edit

That being said, I'd probably break it down at the row level with render, then use partials at the column level

```
<tbody>
  {{render 'row' this}}
</tbody>


<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="row">
  {{partial 'first_group'}}
  {{partial 'second_group'}}
  {{partial 'third_group'}}
  {{partial 'fourth_group'}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_first_group">
  <td>
    hello world
  </td>
</script>
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jafanitu/2/edit

And then create mixins for handling the logic of each `group`  and add those mixins to your controller, to keep your controller clean.  http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Mixin.html

Comment: In that case I will have around 50 different controllers multiply by 100 instances (100 rows in my big table). If I have to pass model into every micro controller isn't it going to kill performance?

Comment: Sorry, I was showing the concept more than giving a recommendation.  updated with what I'd probably do.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass parameters to the view being rendered by the `{{render}}` helper:

```
{{render "myView" someViewProperty="foo" anotherViewProperty=4}}
```

Therefore you can set the `tagName` of your views, so that you get the correct HTML structure:

```
<table>
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th>First column in first group</th>
     <th>Second column in first group</th>

     <th>First column in second group</th>
     <th>Second column in second group</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     {{render 'firstGroup' this tagName="td"}}
     {{render 'secondGroup' this tagName="td"}}
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```